# Change multiple INPUT values with multiple SELECTS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select, input

Maybe someone can help me... I have 5 different SELECTS. I want to change the value of an INPUT after changing the SELECT value. But 5 SELECTS and 5 INPUTS. Each Select has 1 Input.

like this:

```
<select name="select[0]>   // on change of select[0]
<input type="text" name="change_me[0]>  // put the value here

<select name="select[1]>   // on change of select[1]
<input type="text" name="change_me[1]>  // put the value here

<select name="select[2]>   // on change of select[2]
<input type="text" name="change_me[2]>  // put the value here
```

and so on.. currently I'm using this javascript code:

```
$("#select").change(function() {
$(".change_me").val($(this).val());
});
```

but the question is, how can use it for each pair of select and input field. Do I have to write the script 5 times?

Thank you guys!!

Comment: What is `<input type="select">`? Shouldn't that be `<select>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no input element with type select. But if you need the current element to copy the value to the next element, you can do it like this:

```
$(".current_element").change(function() {
    $(this).next().val($(this).val());
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h5ephew0/5/)

Comment: next() seem's not working when I'm using DIVs. Do you know how to handle it if the form elements are in separate DIVs?  `<div>
         <select name="modello" class="select_option">
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>           
         </select>
       </div>
       <div>
         <input type="text" name="">
       </div>`  I tried something with parent() but I didn't found a good solution.

Comment: you should try solving it using parent() than next() than children()

Comment: thank you so much. it is: `$(this).parent().next().children().val($(this).val());`